# postprocessing additive noise in differentially private data

Tags: prior, differential-privacy

when releasing differentially private datasets we often have (or can plausibly assume) knowledge of the noise added to the data to achieve privacy - we can even have good approximations of the scale of noise. Are you aware of any works on utilising this prior knowledge of noise in postprocessing to increase utility of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are algorithms which first add noise to get differential privacy, then reduce the amount of noise by using correlations between results. One such technique is described [here](https://github.com/frankmcsherry/blog/blob/master/posts/2018-03-11.md).

It's also possible to improve statistical estimators based on differentially private information if you can make assumptions on what your data looks like. Section 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.06530.pdf) presents one such technique.

In the general case where you can make no assumptions on the distribution from which the data (not the noise) was generated, and there is no clear correlations between the noisy results you publish, I don't think it's possible.